# I want to see inner values of GWT variables (JavaScriptObjects).

Tags: java, gwt, smartgwt

I want to see **GWT framework's Class's** inner property values at the time of **debug via Eclipse**.

Suppose I have one object of com.smartgwt.client.widgets.tab.TabSet as tabSet 
Now I want to see how many tabs in this tabset via debugging this.

I mean I want to see the values of properties of this TabSet or any other Object like Record, Tab, Layout, etc.

Can anybody help me in this?

Comment: Run your GWT web app in Debug mode and inspect tabSet?

Comment: But it show me only it as JavaScriptObject nothing else.
I mean it doesnt shows me the inner property value as we can see in pure java objects like in ArrayList we can see the size of it and whatever objects are in it.

Answer (score 2):

When running in the debugger, you can use the JsoInspector.convertToInspectableObject() method. It takes a JavaScriptObject and does its best to inspect the object in an IDE-friendly fashion. From the JavaDocs:

> This class provides an API for IDEs to inspect JavaScript objects and
>   is not intended to be used in GWT applications. IDEs that allow custom
>   value renderers for debugging can use it to box JavaScript objects
>   into suitable Java types.

Answer (score 0):

Use API methods on whatever object (e.g. `tabSet.getNumTabs()`, `tabSet.getTabs()[0].getTitle()`) instead of evaluating the object itself.

Unlike in normal java debugging, you won't automatically see all fields and their values by just evaluating an object.